# Rating System For a Game

Tags: probability

I'm developing a ranking system for a game I'm working on. I want my system to be ***consistent***.

My game has $3$ possible outcomes for a confrontation: Win, Lose, Draw

Giving two players $A \& B$ with Rankings $R_A \& R_B$ respectively.

$P_A = P$ of $A$ winning.
$P_B = P$ of $B$ winning.
$P_D = P$ of $D$ winning.

$P_A = \left(\frac{2R_A - R_B}{\frac{3}{2}\left(R_A + R_B\right)}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{P_A - P_B}{P_B} + \frac{P_B - P_A}{P_A}\right)$

$P_B = \left(\frac{2R_B - R_A}{\frac{3}{2}\left(R_A + R_B\right)}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{P_A - P_B}{P_B} + \frac{P_B - P_A}{P_A}\right)$

$P_D = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{P_A - P_B}{P_B} + \frac{P_B - P_A}{P_A}\right)$

If $A$ wins, a certain fraction of $B$'s ranking is deducted and giving to $A$ and vice versa. If there is a draw, a certain fraction of the higher ranking is deducted and giving to the lower ranking. The change in ranking is done keeping in mind the formulae above. If the difference between $R_A \& R_B$ is too high, $\&$ $(R_A \gt R_B)$, there will be no deduction from $R_B$ if $B$ loses.

My aim is to make my system ***consistent*** and scale well.

How should I modify $R_A \& R_B, R_A \ge R_B$ if:
$A$ wins.
$B$ loses.
There is a draw.

Comment: What do you mean by 'consistent'? The system you want sounds just like the [Elo rating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system). Have you looked at implementing that?

Comment: I'm currently considering it.